# Overlay with Google Maps API v3 not reappearing after hide

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I read a lot of examples. They all mention to hide the overlay by

```
overlay.setMap(null);
```

That works fine. But showing it again after hiding it before does not work although it will be shown during initialization. All examples tell me to use

```
overlay.setMap(map);
```

But the overlay does not reappear ?! What is wrong?

See my code at http://jsbin.com/oworor/3/edit

MJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "map" variable is local to the mapInitialize function, change:

```
        function mapInitialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.72, 13.48);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

to:

```
        function mapInitialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.72, 13.48);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Comment: ARRRRG! - Absolutely right! Did not see the obsolete "var map =" for two hours!